# Django model error. `no such table: django_session`

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Making a simple Django model and showing the data on one page.

After messing up my model, I commented the bad code out, removed all migration files except the `__init__.py` file, and deleted the `db.sqlite3` (as described here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html).

However, I started getting this Error `no such table: django_session` on my admin page.

I still have `17 unapplied migration(s)`

How I messed up the model? I put in DecimalType without a default, the CLI gave me three options: they assign a value, I assign a value, or leave it blank. I chose the first option and ever since I've gone down the rabbit hole HELP

It has been suggested that the route to my `db.sqlite3` is wrong so here's my file tree and settings code:
[image]

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from decimal import Decimal


class BuildingProduct(models.Model):
    # CHOICES
    SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        ('MBO', 'MBO'),
        ('VMBO', 'VMBO'),
        ('HBO', 'HBO'),
        ('OPLEIDINGSBEDRIJF', 'Opleidingsbedrijf'),
    ]
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('MATERIALS', 'Materials'),
        ('COURSE', 'Course'),
    ]

    # DATABASE FIELDS
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    categories = MultiSelectField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    schooltype = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default='MBO',
    )
    # price = models.DecimalField(
    #     max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.0000')
    # )
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # SAVE METHOD
    def create(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

CLI

```
➜ djangowim source myvenv/bin/activate         
(myvenv) ➜ djangowim python manage.py makemigrations building_product     
No changes detected in app 'building_product'
(myvenv) ➜ djangowim python manage.py migrate building_product       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: building_product
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
(myvenv) ➜ djangowim python manage.py runserver               
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 13, 2019 - 14:14:08
Django version 2.2.8, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[13/Dec/2019 14:14:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 468
[13/Dec/2019 14:14:24] "GET /static/css/building_product.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 189, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 212, in inner
    if not self.has_permission(request):
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 186, in has_permission
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 392, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 182, in get_user
    user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 59, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 194, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 43, in load
    s = self._get_session_from_db()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 34, in _get_session_from_db
    expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1133, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tara/ProgrammingProjects/djangowim/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session
[13/Dec/2019 14:14:26] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 194446
```

ADMIN page error on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`
[image: admin page error]

Comment: Run **`python manage.py migrate`** (without app name)

Comment: Genius  Can you explain a little bit why that worked?

Comment: This is the command which migrates all ***un-applied migrations***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic:

```
1 delete all migration files!

2 manage.py makemigrations

3 manage.py migrate
```

Maybe flush the old db as well and then just migrate

Answer (score 0):

1. delete db, files cache and files migrations on every app
2. flush
3. makemigrations for each app one by one
4. migrate

**** voilá